# R - Scaling numeric values only in a dataframe with mixed types

Tags: r

I am working with a data frame that has mixed data types (numeric and character) and also has a character key as the primary identifier.  I'd like to scale and center the numeric variables. I've tried using the scale() function, but it requires all fields to be numeric. When I take just the numeric fields and scale them, I have to drop the character identifier to be able to scale them.

My ideal end state is that I have a data frame with character fields and scaled numeric fields.

I realize this is a newbie question, so please be gentle ;-)

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 29):

This can be done straightforwardly using `dplyr::mutate_if`:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it works on datetime column, too. Although it shows up as non-numeric.

Answer (score 27):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
library(MASS)
ind <- sapply(anorexia, is.numeric)
anorexia[ind] <- lapply(anorexia[ind], scale)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would that scale and center (standardize) ?

Comment: @Jim yes that's what it does. Look at `?scale`.

Answer (score 2):

Really the same thing as proposed by Marius, except mutate_if has been superceded with across:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scale))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below does not need any external library:

```
# Scale all numeric columns in a data frame.
# df is your data frame

performScaling <- TRUE  # Turn it on/off for experimentation.

if (performScaling) {

    # Loop over each column.
    for (colName in names(df)) {

        # Check if the column contains numeric data.
        if(class(df[,colName]) == 'integer' | class(df[,colName]) == 'numeric') {

            # Scale this column (scale() function applies z-scaling).
            df[,colName] <- scale(df[,colName])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the other doesn't either, `library(MASS)` is providing the sample dataset.